# If $P,Q\ge 0;P+Q=I$, how to prove $||P-Q||_2\le1$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, matrix-calculus

We define $$\|A\|_2=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$$ as the matrix norm (Spectral Norm, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html).

If $P,Q$ are definite symmetry matrices and $P+Q=I$. How to prove that $$\|P-Q\|_2\le1$$

My thinking:

In fact, from $P+Q=I$, we can conclude that each pair eigenvalue of P and Q are sum up to 1. As a result, their eigenvalue are all less than 1. But what's the next step to say that $\|P-Q\|_2\le1$?

Comment: I don't think you can conclude that. There is no guarantee that both matrices have identical eigenvectors, how can you even select "pairs" eigenvalues?

Comment: The Trace is your friend. It equals the sum of all eigenvalues and it is additive

Comment: Hi, @don-joe, as far as I am concerning, it can be observed when we use the $\lambda I - Q$ and $(I-Q)-\lambda I$ to solve the eigenvalue of $Q$ and $P$, we can find it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Could you please give more details concerning this problem?

Comment: The trace will give you the sum of the eigenvalues, I don't see how it will give you a cap on individual eigenvalues. Your idea with pairs works I think. I added a solution, but again I think both positive or both negative definite is necessary.

Comment: I assumed that both matrices are positive definite, otherwise the claim does not hold, as is easily seen by taking, say, $P=2I, Q=-I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the statement is not true. Take $P = 2I$ and $Q = -I$. Then $P+Q = I$ but $P-Q = 3I$ and $\|3I\|_2 = 3 > 1$

However if you assume that $P$ and $Q$ are both either or negative definite, it could work:

(EDIT it does:) Let $P,Q$ be symmetric, positive definite (spd). Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $Q$. Then

$(P+Q)v = Pv + \lambda v = v \Rightarrow Pv = (1-\lambda)v$

Therefore $v$ is also an eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $(1-\lambda)$. A similar argument shows that every eigenvector of $Q$ is an eigenvector of $P$. Full rank of $P$ and $Q$ implies that every eigenvector of $P-Q$ must be an eigenvector of $P$ and $Q$ also.

Now let $v$ be an eigenvector of both $P - Q$. Then $(P-Q)v = (1-\lambda)v - \lambda v = (1-2\lambda)v$. However both $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ are bigger than $0$, since $P$ and $Q$ are spd. That means $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and that implies $(1-2\lambda) \in [-1,1]$. That is true for every eigenvalue of $(P-Q)$, therefore $\|(P-Q)\|_2 \leq 1$.

If $P$ and $Q$ are both negative definite replace $P := -P$ and $Q:= -Q$ and the same argument as above holds.

Comment: You claim that every eigenvector of P is also an eigenvector of Q. This is absolutely wrong. It it were true, every vector would be an eigenvector of every matrix

Comment: The statement is true because P+Q=I. In general you could make the statement that every eigenvector of every matrix A is also an eigenvector of I - A

Comment: You're right! It works, +1.( Indeed, $P+Q=I$ implies that $P$ and $Q$ commute, as I now see.) Proof: $$PQ=(P+Q)Q-Q^2=Q-Q^2=Q(I-Q)=QP.$$

Comment: Also sorry about my previous comment, it was me who was "absolutely" wrong.

Comment: Thanks! But no need to apologise! :)

Comment: I added my attempt using the trace. Frankly I am not too sure it is ok, if you have some time and you have a look it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using the trace. As shown in comments, the claim does not hold if $P, Q$ are not nonnegative definite. So assume that they both are. In this case the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ of $P$ and the eigenvalues $\mu_j$ of $Q$ satisfy (**EDIT: Warning, there is an issue here** see comments) 
$$\tag{1}
\begin{array}{ccc}
0\le \lambda_j, & 0\le \mu_j,& \lambda_j+\mu_j \le 1.
\end{array}
$$
The first two inequalities come from nonnegative definiteness, the last one is obtained by taking the trace of $P+Q=I$.

Since $P-Q$ is symmetric its norm equals its *spectral radius*, that is, the maximum absolute value of its eigenvalues.

**Here comes the key step**: as strongly hinted by don-joe's answer, the fact that $P+Q=I$ implies that $P$ and $Q$ commute, because 
$$
PQ=(P+Q)Q-Q^2 = Q-Q^2= Q(P+Q)-Q^2=QP.$$
And so the eigenvalues of $P-Q$ are $\lambda_j-\mu_j$. Because of (1) we have 
$$|\lambda_j-\mu_j|\le 1, $$ 
so in particular 
$$
\|P-Q\|_2=\max_j |\lambda_j-\mu_j|\le 1, $$
as claimed.

Comment: I do think your argument is correct, but how does $\lambda_j + \mu_j \leq 1$ follow from the trace? $tr(P+Q) = tr(I) = n$, from just that one could only conclude that $\lambda_j + \mu_j \leq 2n$

Comment: @don-joe: I had read your comment and I agree that there's an error on my part. I *hope* to find some time to fix it. Thank you for your feedback!